# How to screen record with audio?

Tags: unity-game-engine, microphone

I am using 2 different assets:

1. An Audio Recorder: it records audio when started and then it plays it later (Speech Auto Detector).
2. A Screen Recorder (Android Native Screen Recorder).

When Screen Recorder starts, I want the recorded audio to play along with it. I want to screen record it with the audio but when the screen recorder starts, audio stops because both of the assets are using the same mic to capture the audio. Also, both of the assets work fine separately. Is there any solution?

Thank you.

Someone also had the same problem but with different assets so the solution was little different, also I couldn't understand that solution because I am not that experienced with this topic. So, it will be really helpful if you will simplify your answer.

Comment: Do you want it to work on a platform (e.g. iOS or Android)? Or do you only need the Editor?

Comment: I want it to work on android.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We request that you make an attempt at making whatever you are looking for. We are not here to code things for you, were here to help fix problems in said code. If you do not have enough experience in the field to make whatever you need, try following tutorials or build up your skills so you are able to make it.

Comment: Actually I wanted to know If I can switch off microphone after audio recording because after that screen recorder will use that microphone.Only problem I am having is both of them are using same microphone .Is there any Unity function which will stop the microphone after audio recording then it will start when screen recorder will start.Also When I play a pre-recorded audio(something like music) and then I screen record it works but it doesn't work when I record it in the runtime and play it later when screen recorder is on.